# Qt - PainterPath.intersected muy lento

Tags: c++, qt

tengo un QPainterPath que contiene varios poligonos consecutivos de un camino. Dado un nuevo poligono, necesito saber si este se intersecta o no con el QPainterPath y en caso de intersectarse, guardar en un QList dicha interseccion. El codigo que obtuve es el siguiente, pero necesito mejorarlo porque el metodo intersected de QPainterPath tarda mucho. Si yo comento esa linea (que no puedo hacerlo porque lo necesito pero lo hice de manera de ver como se acelera) es terriblemente rapido, pero si lo dejo se viene abajo en el rendimiento. Como puedo optimizarlo o quizas exista otra manera de hacerlo sin QPainterPath?. Gracias

```
QPainterPath aux;
aux.addPolygon(QPolygonF(QVector<QPointF>() << lastLine.p1() << 
QPointF(point.x()+nx, point.y()+ny) << QPointF(point.x()-nx, point.y()-ny) << lastLine.p2() << lastLine.p1()));

QPainterPath pathAux = path.intersected(aux);
if (!pathAux.isEmpty())
    inters.append(pathAux);
```

Aux es un painterpath que me sirve de auxiliar del poligono que armo, en pathAux dejo la interseccion del Painterpath path y el aux. Reviso si hay interseccion y si la hay, la agrego al QList inters.

Comment: Tu problema no está centrado en una parte concreta del código sino que es un fallo de diseño base. La arquitectura que has elegido no es la adecuada... Para subir una montaña puedes usar unas sandalias o unas botas... y con ambas podrás subir... la diferencia estará en el tiempo requerido y en cómo de destruídos acabarán tus pies. Tienes una interfaz gráfica que ya te hemos dicho en varias ocasiones que deberías migrarla a opengl...

Comment: ... QPainterPath no está pensado para el uso que le estás dando y prueba de ello es la pérdida de rendimiento que experimentas cuando contiene un número elevado de puntos y sigues añadiendo más... fíjate que en un gps (con menos potencia de cálculo y rutas más largas) el problema no se reproduce... la arquitectura elegida no sirve.

Comment: Y nuestra capacidad de ayuda al respecto es prácticamente nula porque no conocemos ni el producto ni sus requisitos... los problemas de rendimiento tienen una naturaleza muy distinta a los errores de código... son más como un atasco... que pones un carril más en una calle para que no se congestione y lo que consigues es trasladar el atasco a otras calles aledañas

Comment: @eferion, perfecto. Pues algo similar a esto con opengl, como se haria?...es decir, si tengo que usar opengl, puedo seguir usando qgraphicsitem o cambia todo?. Pregunto porque el ejemplo de Qt de los chips, tiene un boton que activa OpenGl, pero eso mismo puse yo para probar y zaz, se fue todo a la borda. Entonces, existe alguna guia o ayuda para migrar esto a opengl?

Comment: @eferion, con mi comentario anterior me refiero a si puedo escalar, zoom, capas de dibujo como me lo permite QGraphicsItem.